# Difference between geometric approach and counting of dots in a right-triangular arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If I have some dots and arrange them geometrically in a right triangle such that the width (or bottom) of the triangle has $20$ dots and the height of the triangle also has $20$ dots my intuitive thought to calculate how many dots I have used is to calculate the area of the triangle which is: $\frac{20\cdot20}{2} = 200$ hence $200$ dots.

But if I count the dots one by one, they are actually $210$ which is half of a rectangle of width of $21$ dots and height $20$ dots.

> So my question is, what is the difference between the geometrical approach vs the counting approach?

I do understand that if we duplicate the triangle and get a rectangle and divide its area by $2$ we do get the correct $210$ but why the original intuition to use the geometric approach for the are of the right triangle is wrong, somehow is not clear to me.

Comment: Why do you undercount the dots along the diagonal?  Your triangle treats each of them as $1/2$ dot.

Comment: @EricTowers: The dots in the diagonal are also $20$. What do you mean?

Comment: @Jim: If you have $n$ dots, spaced $1$ apart along a line, the distance between the first and last dot is $n-1$, not $n$.

Comment: @quasi: $1$ dot. Next to it $2$ dots one on top of the other, next to that $3$ dots, next to it $4$ dots one top of the other... $20$ dots one on top of the other. I.e. width $20$  and height $20$ and diagonal $20$

Comment: @Jim: Counting dots is not the same as an area calculation.

Comment: @quasi: I understand that, but my question is why the intuitive thought is wrong. Where is the fallacy exactly when viewing the dots as lines and using geometric area?

Comment: @Jim: Try it with a tiny example, say $2$ dots by $2$ dots. The relationship between the dot count and the area of the triangle can be restored (with appropriate adjustments) via Pick's theorem, as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a [fenceposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error.

Smaller example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Four dots wide, four dots tall, gives ten dots, but the right triangle with legs four and four has area eight.

The off-by-one error in detail is believing that using two different heights for the vertical sides in each column (or two different widths in each row), differing by one, encloses the same area as the number of dots.  It does not.  It undercounts the dots along the diagonal by associating each with only half as much area as intended.

Comment: `using two different heights for the vertical sides..` do you mean two adjacent colums i.e. of $3$ dots and then of $4$ dots? `It undercounts the dots along the diagonal by associating each with only half as much area as intended` how is it undercounted? Could you please elaborate that a bit? It is not obvious to me

Comment: @Jim : "for the vertical sides in each column" -- No, the vertical sides to the left and right of each column of dots.  Each dot is getting one square of area; the dots along the diagonal are only getting half a square.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle in question is an isosceles right triangle with legs of length $19$, so it has area
$$
A=\frac{19{\,\cdot\,}19}{2}=\frac{361}{2}=180.5
$$
To find the area by dot counting, let $I$ be the number of inner dots, and let $B$ be the number of boundary dots.

Then for $I$ we get
$$
I=1+2+3+\cdots + 17=\frac{17{\,\cdot\,}18}{2}=153
$$
and for $B$ we get
$$
B=(3{\,\cdot\,}20)-3=57
$$
hence by Pick's theorem

$\qquad$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem#Formula

we get
$$
A=I+\frac{B}{2}-1
=
153+\frac{57}{2}-1
=
\frac{361}{2}=180.5
$$
which matches the geometric result.

Note that the total number of dots is $I+B=153+57=210$, which is greater than the area of the triangle.

If your goal is to count the dots of the triangle by first counting the dots in the $20$ dot by $20$ dot square, then letting $D$ be the number of dots on the hypotenuse, we get $D=20$, so the dot count for the triangle is
$$
\frac{20^2-D}{2}+D=\frac{400-20}{2}+20=190+20=210
$$
Explanation:

If we temporarily remove the $D$ dots on the hypotenuse, we get a count of
$$20^2-D=400-20=380$$
but we need to divide by $2$ to count only the dots below the hypotenuse, so now the count is
$$
\frac{20^2-D}{2}=\frac{380}{2}=190
$$
and finally, we need to add back the count for the dots on the hypotenuse, so the final count is
$$
\frac{20^2-D}{2}+D=190+20=210
$$

Comment: `right triangle with legs of length 19` the triangle mentioned in the post has $20$ dots. How did you come up with the $19$?

Comment: `=(3⋅20)−3` why the subtraction by $3$?

Comment: @Jim: The geometric triangle formed by connecting the dots of the boundary is an isosceles right triangle with legs of length $19$ ($20$ dots spaced one apart yields a total distance of $20-1=19$).

Comment: @Jim: To count the dots of the boundary, we can add $20+20+20=3{\,\cdot\,}20=60$, but that counts each vertex twice, so we need to subtract $3$.